# How can I refer to the calling element in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, callback, css-selectors

For example:

```
<input type="text" size="5" id="question'+$qid+'"onKeyUp="checkanswer('+i+')"/></div>
```

I want to refer to the `"question'+$qid+'"` element inside the function checkanswer(), how to do it?

Maybe I can do it by `onKeyUp="checkanswer('+$qid+')"`, is there other elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you're asking for, but if you're trying to pass the current item to `checkanswer()` you can just do:

```
<input type="text" size="5" id="question'+$qid+'"onKeyUp="checkanswer(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $qid and 'i' are the same number you could do $('#question' + param) in your checkanswer() function (where 'param' is the parameter that 'i' represents).